# how to group bootstrap buttons in two columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen examples of w3c:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_button_groups.asp

but I can not get a group of buttons as follows(I want this):

[image: groups_btn_OK]

I also visited the site but could not find any bootstrap such as what I want(http://getbootstrap.com/components).

My idea is like this: jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10912 but remains separate buttons, buttons corners in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

Juse use simple grid columns
http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/MYdjOj

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xl-6 item"><button class="btn btn-primary">ASD</button></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xl-6 item"><button class="btn btn-primary">ASD</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My idea is like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10912/

but remains separate buttons, buttons corners in the middle

Answer (score 1):

If this is as simple as it appears, then you'd just need a two column table. In each field, place a button with the appropriate classes in each column. Then position the table as you'd like. Although, if you just want the buttons side-by-side, then is suggest simply wrapping them in a div with the class 'btn-group.' I will update with examples.